# Open up and load multiple files in Scilab with the extension .csv

Tags: scilab

I need a way to open all the files in a folder, regardless of the filename. All the files have a .csv extension.

Comment: Yes i just changed it a bit for my program but i used the same concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [listfiles](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/listfiles.html) and [csvRead](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/csvRead.html) like this

```
function doSomethingWithCSVdata(CSV_data)
    disp(CSV_data);
endfunction

csv_files = listfiles('*.csv');

for i=1:size(csv_files,1)

    disp('Opening file: '+csv_files(i))
    csvData = csvRead(csv_files(i),ascii(9), [], 'string');

    doSomethingWithCSVdata(csvData);
end
```